# Rotating a listview cell in Android

Tags: android, listview, rotation

I am trying to make an app which gives the information about the flights and its timing to the user when he enters the flight number, I am able to bring the list of flights in a listview, but I want to enhance it by adding some animation to the cell like the one which we see in the boards at air port, basically i want the cell to rotate with reference to horizontal axis passing through the middle of the cell. Posting the link where you can find some images. I used rotationAnimation but could not obtain the required animation.

[AirportBoard](http://www.google.co.in/images?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=fb8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=Airport+arrival+boards&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1360&bih=578)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a break came back to this and found out that its so easy. I tweaked the RotateAnimation3D class in ApiDemos to make the rotation with respect to X axis and then applied that animation to the Listview with some added delay and it worked.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this a long back, I then moved to iOS dev....my requirement then was to load the list of flights searched by a user in a flip board rotation animation (not exactly an airport board). I looked into my repos and took a sample that I have done, please see it hope it helps. RotateAnimation3D is the one. I have uploaded the code (added a delay in the code so as to see the anim) and video here http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/QYY4Bn98xs5ThPXNhiXlUw

Comment: Link you given here required payment registration. can you send me it on sunboy180887@gmail.com,

Comment: It doesnt require payment click  "Click here to start download from sendspace" link to download. Anyways will send the code.

Comment: Thanks for your nice reply. I got your code. It is very nice. Defiantly it is very useful for my future projects. But actually I am looking for different. I sent you an image on your email id. And thanks i lot for your help. Be in contact on mail. Thank you so much. One up vote from my side.